# ntoskrnl.exe and other drivers causing many blue screens, sometimes computer hangs randomly and makes loud buzzing noise through speakers/headphones

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod

So I've been getting many blue screens lately, and most of them are caused by a variety of drivers, but mostly ntoskrnl.exe. I know this by looking through the logs in BlueScreenView. I've been getting these for a good two months now, according to BlueScreenView. This has been really making me frustrated because sometimes I get a BSOD while gaming or doing work. The minidump files can be found in the .rar file below.

https://mega.co.nz/#!GMUTQQgA!CGBGLKExntC37RF-i3ZycINJZi8XpyfU_ThBol0AEaA

This extra information may help you also:

1. I haven't tried using Driver Verifier
2. I haven't tried using Memtest86+ to check if my RAM sticks are corrupt
3. I haven't done a system restore (I don't really want to resort to this, data takes forever to back up and I got a lot of stuff on this computer)
4. I haven't tried to load the "Last Good Configuration" ( Found the possible fix here, but I want to make sure i'm doing the right stuff here http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000646.htm )
5. I HAVE tried updating my graphic card drivers, which is a nVidia GeForce 6150SE (I know, its poopy), but I still get some blue screens.
6. I've done chkdsk /f, still getting blue screens

As for the loud buzzing noise, I honestly don't know what causes it.

Please help me, guys.

Comment: This happens in a minimal configuration?

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean minimal configuration..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kernel is fine. The last driver which is called before your Widows crashes is netr28x.sys which is the **Ralink 802.11 Wireless Adapter Driver**. But it doesn't necessary mean that this driver caused the corruption.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL (c5)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is
caused by drivers that have corrupted the system pool.  Run the driver
verifier against any new (or suspect) drivers, and if that doesn't turn up
the culprit, then use gflags to enable special pool.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff800033bdb05, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0xC5_2

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!ExDeferredFreePool+249
fffff800`033bdb05 4c395808        cmp     qword ptr [rax+8],r11

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
nt!ExDeferredFreePool
nt!ExFreePoolWithTag
ndis!NdisFreeMemory
netr28x!PostBBPInitialization
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0


    Loaded symbol image file: netr28x.sys
    Image path: netr28x.sys
    Image name: netr28x.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Aug 11 05:39:23 2010
```

Update the driver to the latest version and if this doesn't fix it, activate [driver verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and upload the new dmp files.

The last crash is caused by a driver called networx.sys:

```
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.


nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
nt!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLockFromDpcLevel
tcpip! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
tcpip!UdpTlProviderSendMessagesCalloutRoutine
nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx
tcpip!UdpTlProviderSendMessages
tdx!TdxSendDatagramTransportAddress
tdx!TdxTdiDispatchInternalDeviceControl
networx
0x0
0x0
0x0
nt!KiInitialPCR
0x0
0x0
0x0
networx
0x0
0x0

    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\networx.sys
    Image name: networx.sys
    Timestamp:        Tue Nov 19 18:06:31 2013
```

Comment: I'm trying to update the driver by using this updater located at this [link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&softwareitem=ob-125308-1) When I download it, it installs all of the files in a folder called SWSetup, but after it has done that, nothing pops up after. I went directly to the folder to try running the setup from there, but when I do, I see a bunch of command prompts appear and disappear in my taskbar, then the program compatibility window pops up for me. I tried restarting, and then checked the new version of the device, but it did not update.

Comment: try the latest drivers from here: http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php/downloads/Drivers/Ralink/Wlan/

Comment: OK, the installers run fine and everything else, but when I restart my computer and check in device manager to see if the drivers are updated or not, it's STILL at its old version. I even tried on the Administrator account, and no luck. I'm thinking of deleting the files manually and replacing them manually, or just deleting them and reinstalling them... Oh yeah, also, when I installed the drivers and restarted my computer, I got a bluescreen approximately 2-3 minutes after logging on. hal.dll caused it apparently... Do you want the minidump file?

Comment: when you extract the Exe, there is also a drivers folder. Update the driver from the device manager: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/97061-driver-install-device-manager.html . And yes, share the new dmps.

Comment: Thank you! That method worked. As for the dmp file, here it is: https://mega.co.nz/#!XBtz3bqD!WCFd-9UEhlgmlmBcf9lfEQyvmpGG_PNnxGSb0G-vTtM

Comment: the last cash is caused by **networx.sys**.

Comment: Hmm, ok, that was a program I recently installed to monitor network usage. I'll update it, thanks. I'll report back in this thread if I get any more blue screens.

Comment: Hey magic, I got 2 BSODs today. Here are the minidumps put into a .rar file: https://mega.co.nz/#!eZ8jQbRD!INM9_k1dxPE6FdH0zIb2AnxtfJnUFDFTX3o6qrKfyIQ

Comment: You have a Pool_corruption, and I can't see anything. You must activate driver verifier to get better dumps.

Comment: What settings/options should I use for driver verifier?

Comment: use the standard settings

Comment: Alright, I think I have a new problem now. After verifying my drivers five times, I turned it off and checked my minidump folder. When I did, I found out NO new .dmps were created. I did a few searches on google and I came across this: [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/getting-bsod-but-not-getting-minidump/2ab6f172-8462-428a-a735-c2a65a941ecc) My settings are not the same as the question asker, but it is "%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP" instead. What settings should I change?

Comment: have you got a new BSOD?

Comment: The last blue screen I got was related to the driver "tcip.sys". Since then, I've been getting BSODs but they are not being written to the minidump folder, thus I can't see them in BlueScreenView.

Comment: hm, this is strange. I've never seen this before that enabling DriverVerifier causes that dmps are not written to disk.

Comment: So what settings should I change in "Startup and Recovery"?

Comment: I have no idea, I never seen this before.

Comment: I think they're being written to MEMORY.DMP instead (I can see the file in my windows folder and its over 300MB), but the answer in that link said the default directory should be %SystemRoot%/Minidump. Should I do this?

Comment: zip and upload this dmp file.

Comment: Here it is: https://mega.co.nz/#!SJEUgBBC!G97s-kl2Z-Gv3pQTNpiQAdva5YU_8v9EnXX9qpqJRV8

Comment: this is the old dmp without driver verifier enabled.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll change the directory from %SystemRoot%/MEMORY.DMP to %SystemRoot%/Minidump and verify my drivers tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply, I did what I said above and its still refusing to write minidumps. I'm gonna do chkdsk /f and report back.

Comment: Alright, I got some good news: The minidumps now work. I think chkdsk fixed it. I'll do driver verifier tomorrow.

Comment: I only let Driver Verifier run once and a new dmp file came up. Heres the dl link to it: https://mega.co.nz/#!uQkHiRRA!V_xFFXY0SFG2r4htFqm2n7Y8vqlYzH_1aA70Obz8AT8

Comment: the crash happens inside a Microsoft driver (tcpipreg.sys). This hotfix inlcudes the latest version of this driver: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2923884/en-us Maybe it fixes your issues, too.

Comment: Did that yesterday, sorry for the super long response. I seem to be getting no blue screens so far.. I'll report back in this thread with a minidump file if I ever do